Subscription wide Azure Alert with SQL Script to run in the database from which it was triggered
I'm asking this question because I am getting lost in the woods, and I am afraid that I might end up implementing something that just isn't right, so what I'm looking for is a step by step explanation, explained to me "like I'm 5" because with regard to this side of Azure, I pretty much am.
I am currently looking at setting up an Azure Alert. I have no problem setting one up for a single Azure SQL Server database, triggering the Alert whenever the DTU % on that database runs at an average of 95% for 10 minutes or more.
But we have several hundred Azure databases.... I would love to be able to set up a single alert that is triggered whenever this happens on any one of these databases. I would like to avoid having to configure that same alert over and over and over again, once for each database.
Assuming that this is even possible.... the next thing I would need to do is run a SQL statement against the database that triggered the Alert.
Any tips welcome. Apologies in advance as I'm still at that awkward "I don't even know how to start" stage. It's awful when you're SO ignorant that you don't even know how to ask the right question.

See if this much details is good for you-
Create a Log Analytics workspace and connect your Azure SQL Server databases to it. Follow the instructions in Monitor Azure SQL Database with Azure Monitor metrics and alerts.
Create a Log Analytics query that retrieves the DTU percentage for all databases. Use the following query:
AzureMetrics    | where ResourceProvider == "MICROSOFT.SQL"    | where MetricName == "dtu_percent"    | summarize avg_value=avg(Average), count() by ResourceId

This query retrieves the average DTU percentage for each database.
Create an Azure Monitor alert that triggers when the average DTU percentage is greater than 95% for 10 minutes or more. Follow the instructions in Create and manage alerts in Azure Monitor.
Configure the alert to run a SQL statement against the database that triggered the alert. Follow the instructions in Create an alert rule on a metric from the Azure portal. In the Alert rule details, specify the SQL statement you want to run.

These are the docs which I am referring from

Monitor Azure SQL Database with Azure Monitor metrics and alerts
Create and manage alerts in Azure Monitor


Many thanks Arko.... sometimes it's just a question of familiarising oneself with terminology like "Log Analytics Workspaces". I will investigate these in the coming days and I'll let you know how I get on.

To set up an Azure Alert for multiple Azure SQL Server databases, you can use Azure Monitor. Repeat the steps for all the SQL databases you want to monitor.
You can create a Log Analytics workspace and connect your SQL databases to it. Follow the instructions in  Monitor Azure SQL Database with Azure Monitor metrics and alerts.

In the SQL database menu, select "Diagnostic settings". Click "Add diagnostic setting". Name the setting and select "Send to Log Analytics workspace". Choose your previously created Log Analytics workspace. Select the "SQLInsights" and "Errors" logs. You can choose any other tabs you want accordingly and save it


Then, create your Log Analytics query that retrieves the DTU percentage for all databases. Something like this-
AzureMetrics
| where ResourceProvider == "MICROSOFT.SQL"
| where MetricName == "dtu_percent"
| summarize avg_value=avg(Average), count() by ResourceId

Next, create an Azure Monitor alert that triggers when the average DTU percentage is greater than 95% for 10 minutes or more. Finally, configure the alert to run a SQL statement against the database that triggered the alert.


Configure the alert to run a SQL statement against the database that triggered the alert. You can refer the steps from Create an alert rule on a metric from the Azure portal. In the Alert rule details, specify the SQL statement you want to run.
You can find further details from these MS docs-

Monitor Azure SQL Database with Azure Monitor metrics and alerts
Create and manage alerts in Azure Monitor
Set up alerts on metrics for Azure Database for MySQL - Flexible Server


That is fantastic, lovely, clear and helpful.

Referencing your second image.... I'm not sure what you mean by "the SQL database menu", but I went to the Log Analytics Workspace I created and I found "Diagnotic Settings" under "Monitoring". From there I picked "Add diagnostic settings" and it looks a lot like your second screen shot. Except, under "Categories" all I can see is "Audit" and "Summary Logs".... "SQL Insights" and "Errors" and several other options are missing.

on left side search bar when you type Diagnostic setting, Arent you seeing +add diagnostic setting like this ? What is your role in your subscription? example- owner, contributor, reader- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/built-in-roles

No, alas.... In your screen shot below "Click 'add diagnostic setting' above to configure the collection of the following data" it lists SQL Tuning, Automatic Tuning and several other things. I get to the same page but all it lists is "Audit", "Summary Logs" and "AllMetrics".... Do I need to ask for something to be activated or enabled for us?

yeah I think so, there might be some restriction on your account or role limitations because I can see this option as shared in my screenshot under diagnostic settings.

No worries.... I'll check with our supplier

Just to keep you in the loop, our supplier has not yet responded to my request.
